# Python not able to find modules

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.6, aws-xray

I have a lambda function and I am using aws_lambda_powertools in it. Lambda function project structure is like below-

```
source->Folder
   - handler.py
libs
   - aws-lambda-powertools
   - aws-xray-sdk
   - other libs which aws-lambda-powertools need

handler.py
from libs.aws_lambda_powertools import Logger, Tracer
```

When I run the lambda, it gives me an error "No Module found aws_xray_sdk" even though the module(used by aws-powertools) is there under the libs folder.

Source of Tracer which I am using in my lambda.
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-powertools-python/blob/f5d14e3279276192c6fed0907b84b1dfa23c7b3c/aws_lambda_powertools/tracing/tracer.py

Comment: Which module not found ? Ca you please post the complete stack ?

Comment: Added module name

Comment: Probably your Python path is messed. `$ which python`

Comment: Python version 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Sound like Python don't know where to look. An idea is to put __init__.py files in your directories  so Python knows those are packages

Comment: I already have __init__.py file under source and libs directory(double underscore is there in file name)

Comment: @Knot Have you seen https://github.com/amguerrero/py_aws_lambda_skeleton might give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining your LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your lambda environmental variables?